# Click automático a um certo tempo

Tags: c#

Sou novo na programação em C# e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de criar um programa em que apresente o horário local no formato **HH:mm:ss:mmm** e permita ao utilizador escolher um tempo especifico para existir um *Click* automático do rato, por exemplo o utilizador pretende que exista um *Click* ás **21:01:25:316** o programa fará esse mesmo *Click* automaticamente.

Estive a pesquisar no youtube e em alguns fóruns de C# e não consegui encontrar nada a ver com este assunto. Apenas encontrei alguns tutoriais que ensinavam a programar um *Click* quando um certo período de tempo (escolhido pelo utilizador) passava.

Não sei se este tipo de programa é possível ser feito em C# mas como é uma das linguagens que estou a estudar agora e permite programar em janelas Windows perguntei acerca da mesma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` na classe do seu Form, e depois o código abaixo dentro dessa mesma classe:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto,   CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
//Mouse actions
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

public async Task Clicar() {
    // Pedir ao usuário que informe o horário em que o click deva ocorrer
    // (exemplificado pelas variáveis hora_click, min_click, seg_click, miles_click)
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")); // imprime a hora atual. 
    //Refatorar isso de acordo com sua necessidade e seu Form, 
    //mas a string no formato desejado é DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")
    DateTime objetivo = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, hora_click, min_click, seg_click, miles_click); // definir uma data em que o evento acontecerá
    // você precisa usar o objetivo.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) pra saber se a hora informada pelo usuário é depois do horário atual. Nesse caso o método retorna 1. Se for igual retorna 0 e anterior retorna -1
    TimeSpan wait_time = objetivo.Subtract(DateTime.Now); // pegar o tempo de espera para realizar o click
    await Task.Delay(wait_time); // recomendo uso de await pois não trava a GUI. É bom evitar métodos async com retorno void, mas nesse caso acho que não tem problema
    DoMouseClick(); // faz o click do mouse
}

public void DoMouseClick() {
    uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X; // você pode colocar as coordenadas X,Y pra qualquer valor que quiser, nesse caso ficou a coordenada atual
    uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}
```

Depois é só chamar o método Clicar() da forma que preferir e modificá-lo de acordo com sua necessidade.

Parte do código foi tirado desta pergunta 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c

Aqui o link pro método DateTime.CompareTo
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nunca tinha utilizado nem o async nem o await.
Testei essas linhas de código e está a dar erro no `public async void Clicar()` pois não consigo juntar o async com o void...
Pode ser por estar a utilizar o *Windows Forms* e não o *Console*?

Comment: O contexto não tem problema, é possível utilizar a programação assíncrona no Windows Forms sim, inclusive testei esse código com um Form e deu certo.  O problema é que o retorno `void` não é recomendável em um método assíncrono e sua IDE ou compilador deve estar apontando isso. Tente mudar o método para: `public async Task Clicar()` pois, segundo a [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674893.aspx), *Async methods that don't contain a return statement or that contain a return statement that doesn't return an operand usually have a return type of Task.*

Comment: Exatamente.
Eu é que estava errado e desde já agradeço pelas respostas rápidas e explicativas que ofereceu.
Eu estava a utilizar o Visual Studio 2010 e essa versão utiliza uma framework não compatível com esses comandos.
Obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Para executar o evento `click` você pode chamar o método que representa esse evento. Por exemplo: `public void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) { }`.
Em relação ao agendamento do horário, dê uma olhada [nesse tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703572/how-to-execute-specified-task-at-the-specified-time).